# C++ Pass a string as a value or const string&

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Say I have such simple functions:

```
struct Data {
  string name;
  string value; // Can be very long
};

// Use Data directly to avoid copy. (Not Data*)
unordered_map<size_t, Data> g_data;

// Should I use "const string& name, const string& value"?
void addData(string name, string value) {
  // Should I use any std::move? Like:
  // ... = {std::move(name), std::move(value)};
  g_data[hash(name, value)] = {name, value};
}

// Returning as string seems obvious.
string generateData() {
  // Some computation...
  return value;
}

void test() {
  addData(generateName(), generateDatA());
}
```

I know that the above code works. But I'm wondering whether I should use `const string&` in `addData`? I also wonder `std::move` can make it more efficient?

I'm using at least C++14, and C++17 is also enabled.

Comment: Regarding the context of what you are doing here: What is the purpose of a `unordered_map<size_t, Data>` where the key is the hash of the value? `unordered_set<Data>` would already be a hash map of `Data` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use `std::move`, but not like this. The proposed piece of code would try to hash moved-from strings (pre-C++17 it was unspecified if the strings would be already moved from at that point, see rule #20 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)).

You should pre-calculate the hash and store it in a variable:

```
auto h = hash(name, value);
g_data[h] = {std::move(name), std::move(value)};
```

You should NOT pass `string name, string value` by const reference, since it would prevent you from moving them.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! If it were only for reading it, `const string&` would be okay. But in my case, I need to eventually copy the long strings into the map. As you suggested, passing as a value, and using `std::move` finally seem correct!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: yes, use a reference is better then make a copy for every `addData` function call. If you don't use it, each call will create a (unnecessary) copy of name and value.

For the second question: yes, move can be more efficient.

EDIT:

For a complement of my answer, please refer to @user17732522 comment below.

Comment: The first part is not correct if the answer to the second question is followed. A `const` lvalue reference overload will typically have more cost or about equal cost (for passing an rvalue/lvalue respectively) than a by-value overload if the by-value overload is implemented properly with a move operation. Only using `const` lvalue overloads _and_ rvalue overloads will guarantee less cost in terms of construction operations, although that might have other more subtle costs.